# Why do I receive old data in my gridview on page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

The process I am doing is if `lbl.Text` is "Validated" then disable the checkbox accordingly in grid. The code works fine if paging is not there.
Now the problem is I am using paging and when I click to the next page of grid 
the validated things appear with the checkbox enabled.

I checked through breakpoints. Its loading the previous gridpage values during page load event. And after pageloadevent its going design and loads the new values in grid.

```
//-------loading previous page values of grid here---------

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)row.FindControl("Labely8");
        Label Label23 = (Label)row.FindControl("Label23");
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkRows");
        if (lbl.Text == "Validated")
        {
            checkbox.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            checkbox.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do enable or disable each of the checkboxes individually in the [`GridView.RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event rather than all at once in the `Page_Load` event:

```
void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{    
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkRows");
        checkbox.Enabled = e.Row.Cells["nameOfCellWithLabel"].Text == "Validated";
    }
}
```

Comment: if i place this in GridView.RowDataBound it takes to much time for loading or it doesnt load

Comment: @user: what exactly do you put in GridView.RowDataBound? You only have to enalbe/disable one checkbox in that method (the one of the row being databound). That method will get called for every row in the grid.

Comment: i put the entire  loop inside GridView.RowDataBound event....i want entire checkbox and pages disabled....it diables only in first pages.the other pages it is enabled

Comment: @user: Like i said in my previous comment: *only update the checkbox of the specific row being databound to*. See my updated answer for an example. I think the problem is that `FindControl("label8")`. I think new labelid's will be generated for each page, so you can't use that static id (which is only valid on the first page, which would explain your problem of the checkboxes always being enabled on subsequent pages).

Comment: thanks ...but taking little more time to load a page...any other solution other then this